How to call Informix stored procedure via 4gl
    let aa = '19M/002000000046'
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE motor:p1(aa) 
|______________________________^
| 
|      A grammatical error has been found on line 48, character 32. 
| The construct is not understandable in its context. 
| See error number -4373.
|____________________________________^
| 

  _____________________________^
| 
|      A grammatical error has been found on line 48, character 32. 
| The construct is not understandable in its context. 
| See error number -4373.
|____________________________________^
| 


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Is EXECUTE PROCEDURE legal syntax in Informix-4gl?  Typing your code into Genero I get 'The cursor "PROCEDURE" has not been declared in this program'.
For us it would be something like
PREPARE s FROM "execute function motor:p1(?)"
EXECUTE s USING aa

see more at https://4js.com/online_documentation/fjs-fgl-manual-html/#fgl-topics/c_fgl_sql_programming_010.html
